# Proof convergence for the Newton's method

Tags: functions, sequences-and-series

I am asked to prove that the Newton Iteration to compute the root $x*$ of

$f(x) = |x|^{\frac{3}{7}} = x^{\frac{3}{7}} $ for $ x \ge 0 $

or

$(-x)^{\frac{3}{7}}$ for $x < 0$

will not converge for any starting iterate $x_0 \neq 0$

What I've done so far:

I've computed the first derivative of the function which is equal to

$\pm \dfrac{3}{7} \dfrac{1}{|x|^4}$

then using the Newton formula:

$x_{n+1} = x_n - \dfrac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$

$x_{n+1} =  \sqrt[7]{x^3} - \dfrac{7}{3}x$ for $x \ge 0$

or

$x_{n+1} =  \sqrt[7]{x^3} + \dfrac{7}{3}x$ for $x < 0$

An hint now says that I have to prove that the sequence $(x_n)_{n \ge 0}$ will not converge for any $x_0 \neq 0$. But I do not know how to proceed.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Is the is mathematics or a Mathematica software question?  If the former, please post your question in [math.se].

Comment: This has nothing to do with Mathematica. Voted to close/migrate to math.exchange.

Comment: You will likely find the problem easy if $\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}$ is computed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Your derivative calculation is incorrect:
$$  \frac{d}{dx} |x|^{3/7} = \frac{d}{dx} ( \text{sgn}(x) x)^{3/7} = \frac{3}{7}  \left ( \frac{ \text{sgn}(x) }{x} \right )^{4/7} =\frac{3}{7} \frac{1}{|x|^{4/7}} $$
Thus
$$x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{7}{3} |x_n|^{3/7} |x_n|^{4/7} = x_n - \frac{7}{3} |x_n| $$
can we write $x_{n+1}$ in terms of $x_0$?